# How do I reference assets in .vue files when using Vapor?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vapor

As I want the assets to be distributed on `Cloudfront` upon deployment with the correct URLs.

I am not using `blade` so I can’t use the asset helper. There’s no documentation on this either.

Comment: you can't try to move all assets to public and use `/` before any assets

Comment: Doesn’t work with Vapor.

Comment: What is your vue  folder structure and where is it within vapor?

Comment: It’s the classic structure by default. resources/ , public/ and in Vapor the file surely there but it is referenced incorrectly. Think about it: without the helper it won’t know the Cloudfront url so it gets referenced as vapor-vanity-url-farm.etc/file.ext

Comment: Are You trying to access them from within a Leaf file? Can you give an example? Do you get 404s? I am trying to think about it, but could do with more detail!

Comment: If you're going to deploy the assets to a CDN and then reference them from Vue then you just use the full URL from the CDN right? It has nothing to do with Vapor?

Comment: I am not deploying the assets to the CDN by hand. It is all part of my vapor build. Vapor creates the CDN, uploads my assets and if my .vue files have say images referenced as `/images.png`, then when the app is online, the URL is not rewritten. It appears as `...vapor-a1-farm.com/image.png` rather than `cloudfront.net/blah/image.png`. The question is in conjunction with Vapor but I am sure it involves Mix in somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure you are storing your images in the correct location so they can be processed correctly at build time.

I made the mistake of storing my images in the /public directory. Instead store your images under /resources and in your .vue files make sure you reference them using a relative path.

E.g.

app.vue

> /resources/js/views/app.vue

test.png

> /resources/images/test.png

Then in your app.vue reference your images as such:

```
<img src="../../images/test.png" />
```

Once everything has compiled your images will move to the /public directory.

You then need to inject the CDN via your webpack.mix.js file. Make sure you are setting the resource root to the CDN URL which is passed in via the ASSET_URL by Vapor at build time

```
/* Get the Vapor ASSET_URL */
const ASSET_URL = `${process.env.ASSET_URL || ''}/`

/* Set the resource root */
mix.setResourceRoot(ASSET_URL);
```

Comment: That `ASSET_URL` piece was what I was missing! Thanks!